# How Can I Add Separate Unique Body Class To Label Blogger Blog

Tags: blogger

I want to automatically add unique class names for Homepage and Post page to the <body> tag.

Example:

Show `<body class='homepage-page'>` on homepage

Show `<body class='post-page label-one'>` on Label "ONE"

Show `<body class='post-page label-two'>` on on Label "TWO"

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<b:class cond='data:view.isHomepage' name='blog-view-home'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.isPost' name='blog-view-item'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.isPage' name='blog-view-static'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.search.label' name='blog-view-search-label'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.search.query' name='blog-view-search-query'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.search and !data:view.search.label and !data:view.search.query' name='blog-view-search-default'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.isArchive' name='blog-view-archive'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.isError' name='blog-view-error'/>
<b:class cond='data:view.isPreview' name='blog-view-preview'/>
```

Comment: While posting an answer it is always recommended to add some description about it, so that the future readers may find this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `b:class` tag in order to add a class to the parent element.

Not b:class tag directly after `<body>`

```
<body>
<b:class cond='data:view.isHomepage' name='homepage-page'/>      On homepage
<b:class cond='data:view.isSingleItem and (data:post.labels any (l => l.name == "One"))' name='One'/>     On posts pages and label "One"
```

Note: `data:post.labels` works only inside Blog widget `<b:widget id='Blog1' type='Blog'>`

Comment: Cannot if applied to = <html dir='ltr'>

Comment: It works fine just put b:class tag directly after html tag

Comment: <b:class cond='data:view.search.label == "One"' name='One'/>

Cannot applied

Comment: Please show me the result or your complete code. Your code will give a class name "One" with any element, only on pages of label name One

Comment: Also make sure you have the label name on your blog.

Comment: <b:class cond='data:view.search.label == "Coretan"' name='js-disabled page-page page-custom'/>

Comment: It works, you can see [here](https://prnt.sc/lpe3qy) with my label name "Food" after html element and [this is the result](https://prnt.sc/lpe36z) on Food pages. Maybe you want to add class in  single post pages that contains label name  Coretan not multiple pages

Comment: cannot apllied, [link]https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-jZYTJDspCS0/XAK9PmB31LI/AAAAAAAAAKQ/AS2ocXnaIK4xlVxquxVM7IYHDaLJUpC6wCLcBGAs/s1600/1.jpg in my HTML, [link]https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ckAFO7UHWXU/XAK9Ps0FQjI/AAAAAAAAAKU/MnnmxttwjEYplfC3a6L2wQtRiTc-PxsZgCLcBGAs/s1600/2.jpg

Comment: Oh now, you need it to be in post pages

Comment: In this case you need to loop through post labels but you can apply that only inside Blog widget elements. see my answer update.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='multiitem'
          cond='data:view.isMultipleItems == &quot;true&quot;'/>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='homepage'
          cond='data:view.isHomepage == &quot;true&quot;'/>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='singleitem'
          cond='data:view.isSingleItem == &quot;true&quot;'/>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='static'
          cond='data:view.isStatic == &quot;true&quot;'/>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='archive'
          cond='data:view.isArchive == &quot;true&quot;'/>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='error'
          cond='data:view.isError == &quot;true&quot;'/>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='post'
          cond='data:view.isPost == &quot;true&quot;'/>
<b:attr name='class'
          value='page'
          cond='data:view.isPage == &quot;true&quot;'/>
```